# Setting containter height according to screen size - bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```css
header {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  height: 10%;
}
html body .container-fluid.body-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 12%;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: #171717;
  padding-top: 5vh;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  height: 12%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Some stuff
</header>
<div class="container-fluid body-content">
  Some more stuff
</div>
<footer class="col-md-visible-block">
  Some more other stuff
</footer>
```

I'm using bootstrap and I'm working with a page that should have a 10% header always visible on top, containter in which the actual content is located and can be scrolled through and a footer which should be visible ONLY on `XS` and `SM` screens, so I added the `<footer **class="col-md-visible-block"**>`, but when the footer disappears the container-fluid still has a 12% bottom margin, how do I fix this? Again - I want the footer to be visible only on `XS` and `SM` devices, but then the container should have no bottom margin.
Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, what you want to do but if you want something to be visible only on `xs` and `sm` devices use [`.hidden-sm-up`](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/).

What `col-md-visible-block` does? It's not a standard bootstrap class. Does it hide elements using `display: none` or just `visibility: hidden;`?

In all modern browser you can use also [`calc()`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) CSS function in combination with `vh` and `vw` units. See http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of the question you could always use media queries to remove the bottom margin on a particular view port.

Try and adapt this code for purpose:

```css
//For smaller than md screens
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
  #foo {
    display: none;
  }
}

//For larger than sm screens
@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
  #foo {
    margin: X;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps slightly!

Comment: I guess only using @media will do the job. e.g. `@media (max-width: 800px) {
  /* CSS that should be displayed if width is equal to or less than 800px goes here */
}`